# Distinguish between two similar objects

Tags: typescript

I have this piece of code:

```
interface MysqlError extends Error {
    /**
     * Either a MySQL server error (e.g. 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR'),
     * a node.js error (e.g. 'ECONNREFUSED') or an internal error
     * (e.g. 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST').
     */
    code: string;
}

function f(err: Error | MysqlError) {
    if (err.code) {
    } else {
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Property 'code' does not exist on type 'MysqlError | Error'.
  Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Error'.
```

How can I check which type I got in this function?

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20MysqlError%20extends%20Error%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20Either%20a%20MySQL%20server%20error%20(e.g.%20'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR')%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20a%20node.js%20error%20(e.g.%20'ECONNREFUSED')%20or%20an%20internal%20error%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%20(e.g.%20'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST').%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20*%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20code%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20f(err%3A%20Error%20%7C%20MysqlError)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(err.code)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: The docs covering union types also cover differentiating them: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes the docs cover some of it but unfortunately they don't cover the `in` type-guard which makes most sense here :(

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir true; see e.g. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/typeGuard.html for more options. But `if ((<MysqlError>err).code) { ... }` *is* documented and would work fine. It's arguably also more self-documenting as a discriminant.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Actually `if ((<MysqlError>err).code) ` does not work as a type-gurad unfortunately so inside the if you will need to keep casting ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use an `in` type-guard in this case to test for the existence of the `code` property:

```
interface MysqlError extends Error {
    code: string;
}

function f(err: Error | MysqlError) {

    if ('code' in err) {
        err.code // string
    } else {

    }
}
```